# iterative calculation with serial data lists in python

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am quite new in Python and I am trying to calculate a variable out of serial data streamed as strings from a several sensors. Out of the parameters streamed I want to calculate the concentration of a gas. The first time I ran the code (trimmed version below) it produced a type error indicating 'float' was not iterable. So I created a list 'my results = [ ]' as many helps blogs suggested, and now I get syntax errors on either one of the last four lines of the code. Any orientation would be of great help, thank you.

```
from time import gmtime, strftime 
import os
import msvcrt
import struct
import numpy as np

dataname = 'data.csv'

myresults = []

#preparing variables for calculations and plotting from string
with open(dataname, 'r') as csvfile:  # open file for reading
   for line in csvfile:               # iterate over each line
      parts = line.split(',')         # split string on comma
      value1 = float(parts[0])        # LAT
      value2 = float(parts[2])        # LONG
      value3 = float(parts[3])        # Height
      value4 = float(parts[4])        # Volt 

#Calculate concentration
Conc = (((2*value2)+(8*value3))*12)/value4

myresults.append(Conc)
print "Updated List: ", myresults
print Conc

quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe your should indent the follow lines two level (same as lines you compute valueN) from the view of the code

```
#Calculate concentration
Conc = (((2*value2)+(8*value3))*12)/value4

myresults.append(Conc)
```